# How to place a point on a bar graph, but shift it in the y position

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, axis, point

I'm not sure how to do this, but I've got some points I want to add to a bar graph. However, when I add the point, it ends up in the middle of the bar graph column. I'd like it to be at the bottom of the column.

I created this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/wro10bgp/, which as a green point on it. I would like to put the green point at the bottom of the column and not in the middle.

How could I achieve this?

```
const DATE = luxon.DateTime;

  function arrayToDate(dateArray) {
    return [
      DATE
        .fromFormat(dateArray[0], "HH:mm")
        .toMillis(),
      DATE
        .fromFormat(dateArray[1], "HH:mm")
        .toMillis()
    ];
  }

  class Dataset {
    constructor(xAxislabels, label) {
      this.label = label;
      this.xAxisLabels = xAxislabels;
      this.data = Array(xAxislabels.length).fill([undefined, undefined]);
      this.fill = false;
      this.backgroundColor = ['rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)'];
      this.borderColor = ['rgb(153, 102, 255)'];
      this.borderSkipped = false;
      this.borderWidth = 1;
      this.pointHitRadius = 25;
      this.tension = 0.4;
      this.dragData = true;
      this.tooltip = {
        callbacks: {
          label: function (item) {
            if (!item.parsed._custom) {
              console.log("dynamic couldn't parse the item?");
              return;
            }
            const date = DATE
              .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
              .toLocaleString();
            const time_start = DATE
              .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
              .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
            const time_stop = DATE
              .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barEnd / 1000)
              .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
            return `${item.dataset.label} ${date} ${time_start} - ${time_stop}`
          }
        }
      };
    }

    // Setter
    setData(xAxisLabel, data) {
      const pos = this
        .xAxisLabels
        .indexOf(xAxisLabel);
      console.log("pos: ", pos);
      this.data[pos] = [
        luxon
          .DateTime
          .fromFormat(data[0], "HH:mm")
          .toMillis(),
        luxon
          .DateTime
          .fromFormat(data[1], "HH:mm")
          .toMillis()
      ];
    }
  }

  let myData = new Dataset([
    "Sun 19th Feb 2023",
    "Mon 20th Feb 2023",
    "Tue 21st Feb 2023",
    "Wed 22nd Feb 2023",
    "Thu 23rd Feb 2023",
    "Fri 24th Feb 2023",
    "Sat 25th Feb 2023"
  ], 'task_descript');

  myData.setData('Tue 21st Feb 2023', ["10:30", "11:30"]);

  const options = {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: [
        "Sun 19th Feb 2023",
        "Mon 20th Feb 2023",
        "Tue 21st Feb 2023",
        "Wed 22nd Feb 2023",
        "Thu 23rd Feb 2023",
        "Fri 24th Feb 2023",
        "Sat 25th Feb 2023"
      ],
      datasets: [
          {
          type: 'line',
          label: 'point',
          backgroundColor: "green",
          borderColor: "green",
          data: [{
            y: 'Sun 19th Feb 2023',
            x: '09:45'
          }]
        },
        myData, {
          label: "",
          data: [
            arrayToDate([
              "08:25", "08:39"
            ]),
            arrayToDate([
              "09:45", "09:55"
            ]),
            [undefined, undefined],
            [undefined, undefined],
            [undefined, undefined],
            [undefined, undefined],
            [undefined, undefined]
          ],
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(153, 50, 255, 0.2)'],
          borderColor: ['rgb(153, 102, 255)'],
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 25,
          tension: 0.4,
          dragData: true,
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              label: function (item) {
                /*               if (!item.parsed._custom) {
                console.log("couldn't parse the item?");
                return;
              } */
                const date = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString();
                const time_start = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
                const time_stop = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barEnd / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
                return `${item.dataset.label} ${date} ${time_start} - ${time_stop}`;
              }
            }
          }
        }, {
          label: "",
          data: [
            arrayToDate([
              "08:39", "08:59"
            ]),
            arrayToDate([
              "08:39", "09:00"
            ])
          ],
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 25,
          tension: 0.4,
          dragData: true,
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              label: function (item) {
                if (!item.parsed._custom) {
                  console.log("Tis couldn't parse the item?");
                  return;
                }
                const date = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString();
                const time_start = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
                const time_stop = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barEnd / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
                return `${item.dataset.label} ${date} ${time_start} - ${time_stop}`;
              }
            }
          }
        }, {
          label: "",
          data: [
            arrayToDate([
              "10:39", "15:59"
            ]),
            arrayToDate([
              "11:00", "11:30"
            ])
          ],
          borderSkipped: false,
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(30, 130, 76, 0.2)'],
          borderColor: ['red'],
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 25,
          tension: 0.4,
          dragData: true,
          tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
              label: function (item) {
                if (!item.parsed._custom) {
                  console.log("couldn't parse the item?");
                  return;
                }
                const date = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString();
                const time_start = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barStart / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
                const time_stop = DATE
                  .fromSeconds(item.parsed._custom.barEnd / 1000)
                  .toLocaleString(DATE.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
                return `${item.dataset.label} ${date} ${time_start} - ${time_stop}`;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      indexAxis: "y",
      onHover: function (e) {
        const point = e
          .chart
          .getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'nearest', {
            intersect: true
          }, false)
        if (point.length)
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'grab'
        else
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default'
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          stacked: true
        },
        x: {
          parsing: false,
          stacked: false,
          position: "top",
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour"
          },
          min: "07:00",
          max: "19:00"
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        dragData: {
          round: 1,
          showTooltip: true,
          onDragStart: function (e, datasetIndex, index, curValue) {
            console.log(datasetIndex, index, curValue);
            // console.log("element: ", element);
          },
          onDrag: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
            e.target.style.cursor = "grabbing";
            // prohibit values < 0
            // if (value < 0) return false
            console.log(value);
            //console.log(e, datasetIndex, index, value);
          },
          onDragEnd: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
            e.target.style.cursor = "default";
            // console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  let ctx = document
    .getElementById("chartJSContainer")
    .getContext("2d");
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

-Edit-
Another possibility is rather than a point, to put a small vertical line?

Comment: That is a lot of code. And a single data structure nearly 200 lines long. Is that normal in this sort of thing? Aren't there some conventions to break it up in smaller parts? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Comment: Yes, i could probably break it up, but i was messing in my JSFiddle to come up with something that just 'worked' then i can adapt it into the actual code. There's a lot of hard coded values. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you could use chartjs-plugin-annotation both for point and line.